# What does '<<' mean in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

what does this mean?

```
#define WS_RECURSIVE    (1 << 0)
```

I understand that it will define `WS_Recursive (1 << 0)` but what does `<<` mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess: after it some other constants follow, which are defined as `(1 << 1)`, `(1 << 2)`, `(1 << 3)`, etc.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: that's not very wild at all.

Comment: It's not wild because it is contained in a source file. Now if it were free range, that's different.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`<<` is the [left shift operator](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/expressions/bitops.html). It is shifting the number `1` to the left `0` bits, which is equivalent to the number `1`.

It is commonly used to create *flags*, numbers that can be combined together with `|` (bit or) and various operations can be applied to them, such as testing whether a flag is set, setting a flag, removing a flag, etc.

The reason that they can be combined together without interfering with each other is that each one is a *power of two*, and that is the reason for using `1 << x`, because that yields powers of two:

1 << 0 == 2<sup>0</sup> == 1 == binary `0001`
1 << 1 == 2<sup>1</sup> == 2 == binary `0010`
1 << 2 == 2<sup>2</sup> == 4 == binary `0100`
1 << 3 == 2<sup>3</sup> == 8 == binary `1000`
etc

You can read about bit flags here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Binary_Guide.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit shifting to the left. So 1 << 0 is actually 1. It is usually used this way when you want to define some flags, each of them is one bit set, for example:

```
#define FLAG1 (1 << 0)
#define FLAG2 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG3 (1 << 2)
#define FLAG4 (1 << 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<` computes a bitwise shift to the left. Shifting 1 to the left by 0 bits simply leaves the result as 1.

I noticed also where you got your code from that there's also:

```
#define WS_RECURSIVE    (1 << 0)
#define WS_DEFAULT  WS_RECURSIVE
#define WS_FOLLOWLINK   (1 << 1)
#define WS_DOTFILES     (1 << 2)
#define WS_MATCHDIRS    (1 << 3)
```

That is a way of creating [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), where you OR (`|`) flags together, and AND them (`&`) to check if they're set.

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator shifts the left-hand value left by the (right-hand value) bits. Your example does nothing! 1 shifted 0 bits to the left is still 1. However, `1 << 1` is 2, `1 << 2` is 4, etc. Is WS_RECURSIVE a flag in a bitfield?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit shift. `(1 << 1)` is `2` and `(1 << 2)` is `4`. `(1 << 0)` is `1`, which is rather silly, but at least it's precomputed at compile time.